# Angular Firestore Admin Router Guard

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to prevent regular users from accessing the admin side of my app. Currently, the admin property on the Firestore document is either true or false. If false, they should be redirected to the home page when trying to access the admin side, otherwise, allow the ADMIN to continue to the page.

What should I do?

Here is my admin-auth-guard.service.ts

```
  userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<User>;
  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    this.userDoc = this.afs.doc('users/' + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid);
    this.user = this.userDoc.valueChanges();
    return this.user.map(role => {
      if (role.admin)
          return true
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
          return false;        
    });
  }
```

I believe the code will work, though when initializing the Admin Auth Guard, the request happens too fast and uid is null.

I receive this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null
```

How can I check if the user is an admin when I store the admin variable on a document?

Answer (score 0):

Instead listen to the `authState` and use `switchMap` to change to the inner observable. Also add `take(1)` to your queries, we don't want to leave subscriptions open. Also I would assume that you are using a version of rxjs with pipeable operators. If not, then use `.map`, `.switchMap` and `.take` instead of inside the `pipe()`.

So try the following:

```ts
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

canActivate() {
  return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap(user => {
      // check if user is even logged in
      if (user) {
        return this.afs.doc('users/' + user.uid).valueChanges().pipe(take(1))
      }
      return of(null);
    }),
    map((role) => {
      if (role.admin) {
        return true;
      }
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return false;        
    })
  )
}
```